# Multiple com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream when building after Spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, testcontainers

in the current state I don't know if what I'm doing is wrong, but I've tried bean approach and static field approach with static init block. Tests are passing connecting to mongo, but the build produces multiple errors, that it cannot connect to mongo. Maybe after close of the container. I have multi module spring boot project. I've used bean approach described here, but it does not seem to work fully as it is posting those multiple build errors about prematurely closing connection and such: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testcontainers.at-development-time
My current approach is:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MongoDBContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Network;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.MountableFile;

import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootTestBase {

    static final MongoDBContainer mongoDbContainer = mongoDbContainer();
    static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresDbContainer = postgresDbContainer();

    private static final String DEFAULT_IMAGE_AND_TAG = "mongo:6.0.1";
    private static final String RESOURCE_NAME = "rs-init.sh";
    private static final String CONTAINER_SCRIPT_PATH = "/scripts/rs-init.sh";

    static MongoDBContainer mongoDbContainer() {
        int mongoDbPort = 27017;
        var network = Network.builder().driver("bridge").build();

        return new MongoDBContainer(DEFAULT_IMAGE_AND_TAG)
                .withCommand("/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "dbrs")
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withExposedPorts(mongoDbPort)
                .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource(RESOURCE_NAME), CONTAINER_SCRIPT_PATH);

    }

    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresDbContainer() {
        return new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15.2")
                .withDatabaseName("test")
                .withUsername("postgres")
                .withPassword("abcd");
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void dynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        log.info("=== MONGO DB STARTING ===");
        mongoDbContainer.start();
        try {
            mongoDbContainer.execInContainer(CONTAINER_SCRIPT_PATH);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.host", mongoDbContainer::getHost);
        registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.port", mongoDbContainer::getFirstMappedPort);

        log.info("===  POSTGRES STARTING ===");
        postgresDbContainer.start();
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresDbContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresDbContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresDbContainer::getPassword);
    }

}
```

Do note, that only thing I'm doing is extending this class in the test files not annotated with `@SpringBootTest` and that is it. Maybe I should do something more here?
and rs init file is:

```
#!/bin/bash

mongosh <<EOF
var config = {
      "_id": "dbrs",
      "version": 1,
      "members": [
          {
              "_id": 1,
              "host": "localhost:27017"
          }
      ]
    };
    rs.initiate(config, { force: true });
EOF

sleep 2

mongosh <<EOF
    use admin;
    someDbName = db.getSiblingDB("someDbName");
    someDbName.createUser(
        {
            user: "someUser",
            pwd: "somePassword",
            roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "someDbName" } ],
            passwordDigestor: "server"
    });

    rs.status();
EOF
```

Could you please help me with this issue? It all happend after upgrade to spring boot 3.2.1. I get multiple issues in logs like this one below:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:730)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:606)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:451)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:372)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:102)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:130)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:213)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:156)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:328)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:355)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:808)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:200)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:739)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:603)
```

The strange thing is it happens also in testClasses so compilation, this is very strange in this case. But it happens also after tests. Example below:

```
> Task :module-name:testClasses
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2024-01-10 12:14:28.727  INFO 112868 --- [localhost:32769] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:32769

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:177)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:200)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:739)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:603)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:451)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receive(InternalStreamConnection.java:404)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:224)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:156)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

2024-01-10 12:14:28.729  INFO 112868 --- [localhost:32769] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:32769

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:730)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:606)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:451)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:372)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:102)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:130)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:213)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:156)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:328)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:355)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:808)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:200)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:739)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:603)
    ... 10 common frames omitted

> Task :module-name:test
```

Please, help if you can. [@philwebb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1526192/phil-webb) or someone.